# Using Query Loop with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a Custom Post Type (CPT) named "Events", and I want to add a Query Loop on my front page that displays the upcoming events that my website visitors may want to participate in. On the "Post Type" setting of the Query Loop, I only saw two choices: "Post" and "Page". However, I heard Query Loop can be used with CPT too and I saw a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/P7X9OZWD04A?t=868) showing a Query Loop with CPT options (screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot: Query Loop with CPT options]

The video itself does not cover how to apply CPT on Query Loop, so I tried googling for some tutorials. I found [this article](https://developer.wordpress.org/news/2022/12/building-a-book-review-grid-with-a-query-loop-block-variation/) which may contain the solution I need; the thing is it requires NodeJS which I am not familiar of.

So I wonder if there is any alternative solution to this. Perhaps PHP code that does not require NodeJS? Or a certain plugin that I can install? Thank you in advance!

Comment: is e.g.  show_in_rest set as true when you define your cpt?

Comment: @birgire Wow thank you very much! I just typed in show_in_rest and set it as true, and now it works! :D

Comment: Good to hear it worked. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The post-type dropdown in the *Query Loop* block is populated with data from the REST API endpoint:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/types
```

so we have to make sure the *public* custom post type is registered with `show_in_rest` as `true` for it to be included within that data.